# Ionic Cordova Android update config.xml to allow https://login.microsoftonline.com/ only

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to allow open https://login.microsoftonline.com/ in same app browser, and any other urls need to be opened in the mobile default browser
I added

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to the config.xml but this will open all links in the same app

I tried

```
<allow-navigation href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
```

but it doesn't seem to work since all links now redirected to the mobile default browser.
I am using

```
window.open(URL, '_system')
window.open(URL, '_blank')
```

but i noticed that the flag in the config.xml who controls where to open the links.